# Can't access SuppressMessage attribute at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, suppressmessage

I am trying to create a unit test that will only fail for types which don't suppress the corresponding message.  However, I am unable to access the SuppressMessage attributes on any of my types in my unit tests.  Is it possible to access SuppressMessage attributes at runtime?  I've included a simplified version of my unit test.

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Foo", "Bar")]
public interface IMyInterface { }

public void UnitTest()
{
    var getCustomAttributes = typeof(IMyInterface).GetCustomAttributes();   //Returns an empty array
    //Skip check if message should be suppressed
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your assembly (in which the IMyInterface is defined)  with conditional symbol CODE_ANALYSIS

```
[Conditional("CODE_ANALYSIS")]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class SuppressMessageAttribute : Attribute {
```